# Submit Button Not Calling Function

Tags: javascript

Please forgive any potential lapses in protocol and/or formatting. I'm new at this. Clicking on my "submit" button does not call the function cost(). What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function cost() {
mpg = document.getElementById("mpg");
distance = document.getElementById("distance");
gasPrice = document.getElementById("gasPrice");
alert("<p>" + Math.round((distance / mpg) * gasPrice) + "</p>");
}
</script>

<h1>Trip Cost Calculator</h1>
</head>


<p> Enter mpg (miles): </p>
<input type="text" id="mpg">
</input>
</body>

<body>
<p> Enter distance (miles): </p>
<input type="text" id="distance">
</input>
</body>

<body>
<p> Enter gas price (dollars): </p>
<input type="text" id="gasPrice">
</input>
</body>

<body>
</br>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="cost()"/>
</body>
```

Comment: For a start, you should not have multiple `body` tags in an HTML page, and all content should be in the body.

Comment: First of all you only should have on `<body>` and one `</body>`. In fact you don't even got a `body´ after your head.

Comment: You are not capturing the values of the input fields, only  the input fields themselves.
use the value property of the input fields to get the values.
For example
document.getElementById("gasPrice").value;

Answer (score 1):

You are manipulating objects.Retrieve values using value property like this.

```
mpg = document.getElementById("mpg").value;
distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
gasPrice = document.getElementById("gasPrice").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need value of those elements, not the element it self:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cost() {
mpg = document.getElementById("mpg").value;
distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
gasPrice = document.getElementById("gasPrice").value;
alert(Math.round((distance / mpg) * gasPrice));
}
</script>
```

And you also need to remove all those extra `<body>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your body tags are incorrect. You also need to close your `html` tag. Moreover, use the `.value` property to access the `input` fields.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function cost() {
  mpg = document.getElementById("mpg").value;
  distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
  gasPrice = document.getElementById("gasPrice").value;
  alert("<p>" + Math.round((distance / mpg) * gasPrice) + "</p>");
 }
</script>

<h1>Trip Cost Calculator</h1>
</head>


<body>

<p> Enter mpg (miles): </p>
<input type="text" id="mpg">
</input>
<p> Enter distance (miles): </p>
<input type="text" id="distance">
</input>
<p> Enter gas price (dollars): </p>
<input type="text" id="gasPrice">
</input>
</br>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="cost()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Things go wrong on all kinds of levels here, first and for all **make sure you have valid html**. When working with DOM nodes it's always best to make sure your browser can create a valid dom tree and that works best with valid html. Check http://validator.w3.org

Second, in your `cost()` function **you aren't fetching the values** of the input fields but the fields themself. Ofcourse this results in some weird behaviour which might explain you thinking the cost() function isn't executed. It probably is but is throwing errors you don't notice (check the debug/error console of your browser)

I've fixed up your example, check it, learn from it and read up on webstandards :)

http://jsfiddle.net/vyfqC/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function cost() {
        mpg = document.getElementById("mpg").value;
        distance = document.getElementById("distance").value;
        gasPrice = document.getElementById("gasPrice").value;
        alert("<p>" + Math.round((distance / mpg) * gasPrice) + "</p>");
    }
    </script>

    <title>Trip cost calculator</title>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Trip Cost Calculator</h1>

    <p> Enter mpg (miles): </p>
    <input type="text" id="mpg" />

    <p> Enter distance (miles): </p>
    <input type="text" id="distance" />

    <p> Enter gas price (dollars): </p>
    <input type="text" id="gasPrice" />

    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="cost()"/>

</body>
​
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. That helps a lot. 

Yeah. That <body> issue is super embarrassing. :)